# Updating deprecated WAS-MQ code

Tags: java, ibm-mq, deprecated

I am working on migration of a WAS 6.1 based application to WAS 7.0
I found below two statements

```
com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment.securityExit = null; // 1
```

and

```
MQQueueConnectionFactory factory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
factory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP); // 2
```

1. On line# 1 `securityExit` is [deprecated](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.mq.java.doc/com/ibm/mq/MQEnvironment.html#securityExit) the doc says:

   *`The security exit used when connecting to a queue manager. It allows you to customise the security flows that occur when an attempt is made to connect to a queue manager.
   If you want to provide your own security exit, define a class that implements the MQSecurityExit interface and assign securityExit to an instance of that class.
   If you set this field to null no security exit is called.`*

   What I understand from this is `com.ibm.mq.MQSecurityExit` interface needs to be implemented. What does **assign securityExit to an instance of that class** mean ?
2. On line# 2 `JMSC` is [deprecated](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/JMSC.html). The doc says:

   *`This parameter can be passed to MQConnectionFactory.setTransportType(int) to indicate that the application should connect to the queue manager in client TCP/IP mode.`*

   Also for the interface the doc says:

   *`Use the constants defined in the classes in the com.ibm.mq.constants package instead`*

   The doc for [com.ibm.mq.constants](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/constants/package-summary.html) is of not much help.

Any help in replacing the deprecated statements is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It means you need to create an instance of your implementation of MQSecurityExit class and set the security exit property. Something like this

```
   // in MySecurityExit.java
   class MySecurityExit implements MQSecurityExit 
   {
       // you must provide an implementation of the securityExit method
       public byte[] securityExit(MQChannelExit       channelExitParms,
                                  MQChannelDefinition channelDefinition,
                                  byte[]              agentBuffer)
       {
           // your exit code goes here...
       }
   }

   // in your main program...
   MQEnvironment.securityExit = new MySecurityExit();
   ...    // other initialisation
   MQQueueManager qMgr        = new MQQueueManager("");
```

The `setTransportType` method determines how your application connects to WMQ queue manager, whether application and queue manager communicate over shared memory or socket or HTTP etc. Possible values for this method are defined [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/JMSC.html)

Comment: 1. What should go at `// your exit code goes here...` that will make the code behave similar to `com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment.securityExit = null; ` ?

 2. You are pointing me back to the [JMSC](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/JMSC.html) page, which is deprecated

Comment: com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment.securityExit=null means you don't to use any security exit. Then you don't need to implement any security exit at all let alone adding anything in "//your exit code goes here".

Comment: For the setTransportType you can use the `WMQConstants` that is not deprecated.

  `factory.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_DIRECT_TCPIP);`